# Streaming x264 with packet loss

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, x264

I write the program where I use x264 as the coder. 
I use the following parameters:

```
av_opt_set (codecContextH264[numberCoder]-&gt; priv_data, "profile", "baseline", 0);
av_opt_set (codecContextH264[numberCoder]-&gt; priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
av_opt_set (codecContextH264[numberCoder]-&gt; priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
codecContextH264[numberCoder]-&gt; bit_rate =bitrate;
codecContextH264[numberCoder]-&gt; bit_rate_tolerance=bitrate-5000;
codecContextH264[numberCoder]-&gt; width = w;
codecContextH264[numberCoder]-&gt; height = h;
codecContextH264[numberCoder]-&gt; time_base.den = fps;
codecContextH264[numberCoder]-&gt; time_base.num = 1;
codecContextH264[numberCoder]-&gt; pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
codecContextH264[numberCoder]-&gt; gop_size = fps*3;
codecContextH264[numberCoder]-&gt; keyint_min = fps*3;
codecContextH264[numberCoder]-&gt; max_b_frames = 0; 
codecContextH264[numberCoder]-&gt; slices = (int) (w*h)/1500+1;
```

I use only I and P frames. 
What x264 settings I shall use that could lose P frames? 
Perhaps x264 has no such opportunity?!
I read that if to use a "base" profile, it is possible to lose P frames...
Help please.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the `gop_size` and `keyint_min` to 0 - that should result in a stream with only I frames, but that kind of looses the sense of compression as such.

The further is based on the assumption that you are using RTP over UDP - if you are streaming in an environment where packet loss is high, why not use TCP or implement some kind of quality service where if you see that RTP sequence numbers are missing you force the source to issue a new keyframe.